# TIBCO EMS 6.0 with WLS 10.3.1.0 foreign server configuration

Tags: weblogic-10.x, tibco-ems

TIBCO EMS 6.0 with WLS 10.3.1.0 foreign server configuration not working

Posting message from SOAPUI to EMS(JNDI/Queue) to WLS(JNDI)

Hi, I followed the steps in order to integrate Tibco EMS 6.0 with WLS 10.3.1.0 for setting foreign server,
I am posting the message on EMS queue and the messages are not appearing in the WLS JMS JNDI,

With Integration following is scenario
SCENARIO Using SOAP UI posting message: I have configured SOAP UI with Hermes JMS which is configured with TIBCO EMS and WLS server (10.3.2.1)
I have added new Foreign server in WLS and below are the steps performed so far when I place a SOAP message using SOAP UI, this message wont appear in WLS JNDI

SOAPUI to EMS(JNDI/Queue) to WLS(JNDI)

Still I managed to extrapolate the below steps from the WLS 10.3.1.0 JMS foreign server config
instructions to have them work with TIBCO,

In Tibco ems 6.0
Created 1 queue:
Falcon.EMS.queue

Created 1 connection factory:
QueueConnectionFactory

Created 1 JDNI:
jndi.falcon.ems.queue

JNDI: jndi.falcon.ems.queue is mapped to Queue: Falcon.EMS.queue
end In Tibco ems

In WLS 10.3.2.1 server
1.Added required ems jar files in WLS lib folder and also classpath is set
2. Start the WLS 10.3.2.1 Server
3. Open the WLS 10.3.2.1 admin page: http://localhost:7001/console
4. Select Services -> Messaging -> JMS Modules
5. Click on "oms-jms-module"
6. Create a Resource "Foreign JMS server"
Name: ForeignServer-EMS
JNDI Initial Context Factory: com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory
JNDI Connection URL: tibjmsnaming://localhost:7222

7. Under ForeignServer-EMS
   a. Click on Destinations -> New
   i. Name: ForeignDestination-JMS
   ii. Local JNDI Name: oracle/communications/ordermanagement/WebServiceQueue
   iii. Remote JNDI Name: jndi.falcon.ems.queue
   b. Click on Save
8. Under ForeignServer-EMS
   a. Click on Connection Factories -> New
   i. Name: ForeignConnectionFactory-JMS
   ii. Local JNDI Name: queueconnectionfactory
   iii. Remote JNDI Name: QueueConnectionFactory
   b. Click on Save

For sometime rename the JNDI name for queue oms_ws_requests to some other name as it will confict the JNDI name which is used in above configuration mentioned in point ii. Local JNDI Name: oracle/communications/ordermanagement/WebServiceQueue

but WLS admin server console fails with errors saying...

```
<+++ lookup(weblogic.jms, weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode) succeeded>
<+++ lookup(weblogic.jms.XAConnectionFactory, weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteObject) succeeded>
<+++ lookup(oracle, weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode) succeeded>
<+++ lookup(oracle.communications, weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode) succeeded>
<+++ lookup(oracle.communications.ordermanagement, weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode) succeeded>
<+++ lookup(oracle.communications.ordermanagement.WebServiceQueue, weblogic.deployment.jms.ForeignOpaqueReference) succeeded>
<WSEE:107>javax.jms.JMSException: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: weblogic.jms.common.InvalidDestinationException: [JMSClientExceptions:055142]Foreign destination, Queue[Falcon.EMS.queue]<JmsQueueListener.handleConnectionException:331>javax.jms.JMSException: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: weblogic.jms.common.InvalidDestinationException: [JMSClientExceptions:055142]Foreign destination, Queue[Falcon.EMS.queue]
at weblogic.wsee.server.jms.JmsQueueListener.connect(JmsQueueListener.java:258)
at weblogic.wsee.server.jms.JmsQueueListener.run(JmsQueueListener.java:357)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
```

Is there any issue with working of WLS JMS - Tibco EMS for posting SOAP messages to OSM JNDI)

I found one similar issue at: [Weblogic EJB connection to external Tibco EMS JMS Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818018/weblogic-ejb-connection-to-external-tibco-ems-jms-queue) answer that is provided at this link is as below:
Have finally achieved this - due to a bug in Weblogic 10.3 this isn't as simple as it should be.

1. Create a foreign server with all the normal details (local/remote JNDI lookup names for destination and connection factories).
2. Create a local WL user with the same name as the remote EMS user, including password.
3. Create an ejb credential mapping (NOT security credential mapping)

   - do this by clicking on the relevant deployment, click on the relevant ejb name in the list, then Security tab then Credentials Mapping tab.
   - add the same name for WLS and Remote users (password doesn't seem to be necessary here).

Is this issue relevant to the [Weblogic EJB connection to external Tibco EMS JMS Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818018/weblogic-ejb-connection-to-external-tibco-ems-jms-queue)

If yes, I am not able to create the user name in WLS same as that in tibco ems as mentioned in point 2. When I am creating credential mapping as per above point 3 the user name for WLS is not editable it creates its own user as cross-domain.

Are there any steps to be followed for point 3.

Comment: Please post the answer in a separate **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110239/tibco-ems-6-0-with-wls-10-3-1-0-foreign-server-configuration#post-form)** section and mark your issue as resolved.