# Setting up MDBs to consume JMS messages in Weblogic 10.3.5

Tags: jms, weblogic, installation, message-driven-bean, tibco

I'm trying to set up part of an application which uses MDBs to consume messages from a JMS Queue.  I've looked through the Oracle documentation but can't seem to make sense of it.  Examples on the internet seem to be for situations where your JMS server is the same weblogic server where you are consuming but in my case there is a separate server.

I've found this post [Weblogic EJB connection to external Tibco EMS JMS Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818018/weblogic-ejb-connection-to-external-tibco-ems-jms-queue) which gives broad strokes but seems to be written more for experienced weblogic users.

Specifically with the linked here is where I'm having trouble:

> > Create a foreign server with all the normal details (local/remote JNDI lookup names for destination and connection factories).

Not sure how to do this.

> > Create a local WL user with the same name as the remote EMS user, including password.

I cannot do this as my password is less than 8 characters

> > Create an ejb credential mapping (NOT security credential mapping)
> >
> > ```
> > do this by clicking on the relevant deployment, click on the relevant ejb name in the list, then Security tab then Credentials Mapping tab.
> > add the same name for WLS and Remote users (password doesn't seem to be necessary here).
> > ```

Under Security I see Application/Module Scope tabs and Roles/Policies underneath those.

Can anyone give more detailed steps on how to set up a simple MDB in Weblogic 10.3.5 which consumes JMS messages from an external server (Tibco EMS)?

I have an ldap url, a selector (to filter out unwanted messages, not completely necessary), username and password, Queue name, EMS server url (which specifies a port), connection factory ldap.  What do I do with this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure a foreign server in weblogic and inside the foreign server you can provide the connection factory & destination details. The username, passwd & queue name that you have will be required to create these weblogic admin objects.

[Weblogic foreign server configuration](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28271_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/jms_modules/foreign_servers/ConfigureForeignServers.html)

While creating the destination you can provide the local jndi name which you can use in your MDB Activation configuration to connect to.